# The special unitary group SU(2) is homeomorphic to the 3-sphere

Tags: general-topology, linear-groups

> The special unitary group is defined as 
>   $$\mathrm{SU}(2) = \{A\in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C}) \mid A(\overline{A})^T=I_{2\times2}\}.$$
>   Show that this is homeomorphic to the $3$-sphere
>   $$\mathbb{S}^3 = \{(a,b)\in \mathbb{C}^2\mid |a|^2+|b|^2=1\}.$$

I know that for a map to be a homeomorphism the function needs to be continuous, function is bijective and the inverse of this function is continuous. However, I am not sure how to show that two things are homeomorphic.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I replaced the image with text.

Answer (score 6):

Two topological spaces $X,Y$ are said to be **homeomorphic** if there is a function $f:\:X\to Y$ which is a homeomorphism.

So all you got to do is find one. Usually there is a natural way to define such function, and that is the case right here : think of a general matrix in $SU2$ - how does it look? how many parameters, or values, define it? where would you send it then?

If needed i'll give a specific solution.

**p.s**

per your request i'll add more details:

every $M\in SU(2)$ can be desribed as $\begin{bmatrix}
a & -\overline b \\
b & \overline a
\end{bmatrix}$, and every $a,b$ describes a unique $M$. therefore send $f(M)=(a,b)$. this is clearly a bijection (the inverse is $(a,b)\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
a & -\overline b \\
b & \overline a
\end{bmatrix}$ , and I'll leave it to you to try to show that is a homeomorphism. Again, if required, i'll assist.

**p.s.s**

Per your request, a prove that every matrix is of that form:

Let $M=\begin{bmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d
\end{bmatrix}\in U$. we have $M\overline M^t$= \begin{bmatrix}
aa^*+cc^* & ab^*+cd^* \\
ba^*+dc^* & bb^*+dd^*
\end{bmatrix}, and we must have $M\overline M^t=I $. the solution for these 4 equations is $c=-\overline b$ and $d=\overline a$, please check yourself.

Comment: I have tried working out the inverse of A but I doubt this will be of much use. I am trying to figure out a way to get from one to the other. A specific solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Added details. If my answer is usefull please mark it as one and upvote it.

Comment: why is $M \in SU(2)$ described as the matrix you have given? How is this obtained?

Comment: added. Also please hit "accept this answer" when you think I helped you enough

Comment: @user234238: What kind of topology do you define on both?